# Issue with Intel compilation on macOS 10.15 Catalina : catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdlib.h"

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, intel, macos-catalina

I try desperatly to compile with c++ intel compiler (`icpc`) a simple code that I was used to compile on my previous macBook 10.14.

Now, since Headers don't exist anymore with 10.15 Catalina, the compiler has difficulties to find `stdlib.h`. Here the output I get :

```
icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -xHost -fp-model strict -prec-div -prec-sqrt -fma -ftz -mp1 -qopenmp -Wall -c -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.258/mac/mkl/include  -mkl=parallel main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h(301),
                 from /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.258/mac/compiler/include/math.h(177),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath(304),
                 from TSAF.h(1),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h(20): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdlib.h"
  #include_next <stdlib.h>
                          ^

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 4)
make: *** [Makefile:13: main.o] Error 4
./main_intel.exe: No such file or directory
```

I tried a lot of potential workarounds from the net but none works. I would like to avoid to create a directory `/usr/include/` by removing the security system of my macBook.

I thought maybe this would work by downloading XCode_12.0.1 but same problems remain.

For the moment, I have the version Catalina OS 10.15.7, all has been updated.

**EDIT 1:** There is something that I don't understand : on my previous macBook 10.14, I didn't need to use the headers of clang c++ for intel compilation.

If anyone could give me a suggestion/clue/track, this would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command in the Terminal

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

And then check if proper developer tools are selected instead of the command line tools

```
xcode-select -p
```

Comment: This doesn't work, after `xcode-select -p` , I get `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: Moreover, I would like to be independent from Xcode and be able to compile directly on the terminal.

Comment: It should work if you have installed Xcode. If you would like to be  independent from Xcode, you have to install MacOS SDK and clang in any case.

Comment: @S;M. It should work for you but not for me, I installed Xcode and the compilation is still not achieved. Before, with my previous macBook 10.14, I had not Xcode and everything was working well. This is due to the fact that in recent versions of Catalina, headers are missing and I don't know how to compensate it.

Comment: I use Catalina, you are not the only Catalina user. If you have installed Xcode you should not get /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools. If you are getting it, you have not installed Xcode, probably just copied it and you should run it at least once.

Comment: Finally issue fixed by removing Xcode (that's not useful in my case) and keep CommandLineTools : then simply create a /usr/include directory. Thanks